# parsing an Ldif file to json in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, ldap, ldif

I have an LDIF file and i need to parse it to json format to work on it in nodejs , so I'm asking if there is any library to do that or any other solutions?
Thanks for helping

Comment: Hie Did you find any solution for this I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. This is the only solution I've found yet.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldif